# Fetching data from form in opencart

Tags: opencart

In an Opencart application, i have a checkout process includes several steps. Step 2 is to enter delivery address. and in this step "enter city" field is there in which user has to fill his city. Now in step 4 there is payment method in which i want to apply a condition that if city is this cod will be available so how to fetch that city value to use it in step 4. Both these steps have different views(.tpl), different controller. 
If this approach is not good then please suggest another one. I am new to opencart

Comment: Which opencart version do you use? please provide the checkout controller code, I think that data is saved in the session

Comment: Guy L thanks for your kind support... i found the solution.. you are right i solved it from the controller file